# Passing an ID thru a Request Laravel

Tags: laravel

What I want is to pass the logged on users id

ArticleRequest.php

```
    namespace App\Http\Requests;

    use App\Http\Requests\Request;

    class ArticleRequest extends Request {

        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize() {
            return true;
        }

        //validation rules
        public function rules() {
            return [
                'title' => 'required|min:5',
                'content' => 'required',
                'user_id' => 'required|numeric',
                'category_id' => 'required|numeric',
                'published_at' => 'required|date',
    //            'image'=>'required|image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp'
            ];
        }
        //custom message
        public function messages() {
            return [
                'title.required' => 'A title is required',
                'content.required' => 'Write a content',
                'category_id.required' => 'Pick a Category',
    //            'image.required' => 'Image should be png,jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp in format'
            ];
        }

    }
```

ArticleController.php

```
  //storing articles
    public function store(ArticleRequest $request) {
        $id = \Auth::id();
        $request['user_id'] = $id;
        Article::create($request->all());
        flash()->overlay("Your Post has been added!", 'Congratulations');
        return redirect('article');
    }
```

the above code won't work I don't know. I'm just experimenting it. But still it won't work. I want to pass the currently logged on user's id into the user_id column.

Comment: logged in user id: `Auth::user()->id;`

Comment: Take note: I am using request? Shall I put it in a controller sir?

Comment: yes. anywhere you need,

Comment: `$request::user()->id;` Typehint the `Request` class

Comment: I'm still confused. I want to pass the currently logged on users_ id and  pass it in the user_id column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation provided by your `ArticleRequest` form request object is done before the controller method is even called. Therefore, it doesn't matter what code you add in your controller, you won't be able to modify the data in the form request object before validation occurs.

If the `user_id` is not coming in through the request data, then you need to remove it from the rules in your form request object.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the `user_id` with the request params:

```
Article::create(['user_id' => \Auth::user()->id] + $request->all());
```

Or if you have relationships set up:

```
Auth::user()->articles()->create($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArtileRequest` is of type of `FormRequest`, you can not just add a value into it like that.

Here's a code sample that might work for you:

```
    //storing articles
    public function store(ArticleRequest $request) {
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['user_id'] = \Auth::user()->id();
        Article::create($input);
        flash()->overlay("Your Post has been added!", 'Congratulations');
        return redirect('article');
    }
```

Comment: @SteD `FormRequest` extends `Illuminate\Http\Request`, which implements the `ArrayAccess` interface. Therefore, you can add data to the `FormRequest` as the OP attempted.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you should write your application logic within your controller, this will make you write the same piece of code in others parts of your application resulting in duplicated code.

## Solution

I also need to tell you that this is not the best approach, but it should do the trick and it is clean.

### User.php

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
}

public function publishArticle(Article $article)
{
    return $this->articles()->save($article);
}
```

### ArticleController.php

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $request->user()->publishArticle(new Article($request->all()));

    ...
}
```

Remember, you can also access the user through the request.

```
/**
 * Get the user making the request.
 */
$user = $request->user();
```

Comment: Yeah I followed +patricus comment that I removed the 'user_id' rule and followed your code. Why does it automatically inserted the data? Because I didn't pass any 'user_id' parameter.

Comment: We are retrieving the current logged in user from the request, if you have set a relationship Laravel will magically do the association.